# Change the appearance of a UIView while tapped down (but not yet released up)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a custom `UIView`, to which I have added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the view in order to detect taps (i.e. finger press and release) on the view. This works fine.

However, I now want to change the appearance of the UIView (making it a bit darker) while the finger is pressed on the view (just like the behavior of a UIButton).

How do I do this?

Comment: Is subclassing UIButton not an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the appearance in `-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`.

Comment: To clarify, a tap gesture recognizer fires when you lift the finger, so it won't work for this purpose. You have to implement a set of lower-level `touches...:withEvent:` methods to know when the finger is down and when it's up.

Comment: @Costique and @fannheyward: Thanks, these methods work great. However, just to confirm one thing: When I tap very quickly on the view (i.e. touching the screen very briefly), the `touchesEnded:` gets sent very quickly after `touchesBegan:`, which doesn’t provide the view with a chance to display the darker “down” color. I worked around this problem by measuring the time between the two method calls; and when the time is low enough (less than 1 sec), I use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` to delay the return to the normal color. This works fine. However, is this the best approach?

Comment: @Enchilada I'd say that's OK. The delay can be made as short as the animation duration.